# Measure native DLL memory usage from c# code

Tags: c#, .net, memory, measure

I'm using a vendor-provided C++ DLL, that I call with `DLLImport`, to parse and process files containing many object types.

I need to have a correlation between number of objects in the file and memory usage, in order to (hopefully) be able to prevent OutOfMemoryExceptions that happen sometimes.

---

### Update

To be more clear on what I'm trying to measure and why : the out of memory exception is expected, because some very complex files take up to 7gb of memory to load (as measured by perfmon): they are 3D maps of sometimes huge and intricate buildings, from the walls down to the individual screws and bolts, including the trees outside and the tables and chairs in each room.

And since the DLL can load multiple maps in parallel (it's on a web server and the process is shared), loading 2x 7gb files understandably triggers an OutOfMemoryException on a machine with 8gb of RAM.
However, 7gb is pretty rare, most of the maps take up about 500mb, and some take 1 to 2gb.

What we really need is **not** to find a memory leak (yet...), but be able to know **before loading the file** how much memory it will probably use. So when a user tries to load a file that we calculate will probably take about 2gb of RAM while the machine has 1gb free, we do something about it; from spinning up a new VM in Azure to preventing the user from working, we don't know what yet, but we can't let the DLL crash the whole server down each time.

And in order to do that, I want to find out, for instance, "the DLL uses 1mb of memory for each 100 geometry object".

---

So I have a bunch of files to test (about a hundred), and I want to load them up in order, measure the memory usage of the native DLL (before and after), unload the file, process the next. Then I get a nice CSV file with all the data.

I have tried `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64` but it only gives me the current process memory, but the DLL doesn't seem to live in the current process, since most measures give me 0 bytes (difference between before and after file load).
I also have tried `GC.GetTotalMemory()` but it's not much better, the files are seemingly all exactly 1080 bytes.

```
private static void MeasureFilesMemoryUsage(string[] files) {
    foreach (var file in files) {
        var beforeLoad = MeasureMemoryUsage();

        wrapper.LoadFile(file)

        var afterLoad = MeasureMemoryUsage();

        wrapper.Unload();

        // save beforeLoad and afterLoad
    }
}

private static long MeasureMemoryUsage() {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    return System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64;
}
```

I know about tools like VMMAP or RedGate Ants Memory Profiler (or simply performance counters), but these do not allow me to match the memory usage with a specific loaded file, I would have to load files one by one, pause the program, make a measure in the tool, and write down the results. Not something I want to do on 100 files.

How do I measure memory usage of a specific C++ DLL from .Net code?

Comment: A DLL cannot allocate out-of-process memory; the code in a DLL is logically part of the process (and as such, you cannot distinguish how much memory is allocated by each DLL, barring stack traces to allocation functions). A DLL can call upon out-of-process COM servers and the like, but that would be unusual. `VirtualMemorySize64` should change if the process allocates memory. Perhaps include a brief code snippet of how (and what) you're measuring. (Also, `PrivateMemorySize64` might be a better measure.)

Comment: DllImport loads library into current process just once - it does not unload it (until app domain dies). And good C++ library should not consume additional memory AFTER it performs heavy operation - all resources should be freed by it. It of course will consume memory during operation, but not after. So not sure what exactly you are trying to measure.

Comment: 1080 bytes is very small. If the library allocates anything at all, it'll probably not be detectable from already allocated pages, so working file by file isn't likely to get you anything. If you really want to detect where out of memory conditions are coming from, you are far better off 1) causing an OOM and 2) getting a memory dump and analyzing it to see where it's coming from. It could be a very small memory leak that needs to be sustained over hours before you see anything, for example, and profiling individual loads isn't going to show that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : I have added a stripped-down code sample of what I'm doing. @Evk : the DLL loads files to be manipulated in 3D, so it holds the file (or rather, a representation of the file) in memory until the process exits or I tell it to "destroy" the file. After the `LoadFile` from the example we usually call `Rotate`, `Zoom`, etc.

Comment: @JeroenMostert 1080 bytes is just plain wrong, actually. Perfmon tells me some of the files I load use 2gb of memory, and most of them use about 500mb. I have another sample program that just loads one file and never releases it, I could use it to take memory snapshots and make measurements by hand, but I really, really don't want to do it for a hundred files. I'm not trying to track down memory leaks, but normal memory usage, to correlate it to file data. I'll try to explain better in my post.

Comment: I'd try to use `WorkingSet64` instead of `VirtualMemorySize64`.

Comment: @Evk: well WorkingSet64 loos VERY promising! I have much more realistic data! I'll look in details to see if it matches, thank you! And please post an answer so I can accept it :P

Comment: Still not sure about details... And does VirtualMemorySzie64 increases after _first_ call to that c++ dll? And if yes - by how much?

Comment: VirtualMemorySize64 is the correct measurement since that is the one that generates OOM.  WorkingSet64 is useless since it measures RAM, not address space, and heavily depends on what else is going on in the machine.  Getting a measurement of 0 is expected, especially on a server, you'd have to allocate enough to force the GC to create more heap segments.  ServerGC starts out with big ones.  You cannot get OOM by loading 7 GB of data on a machine with 8 GB of RAM, there is more than one reason for getting OOM.

Comment: @HansPassant but OP measures memory consumption of unmanaged c++ dll. Why VirtualMemorySize64 does not increase between calls to that dll (but WorkingSet increases)? Because it allocated large memory segment beforehand? GC is not related to this, since that is C++ dll.

Comment: It does not work any differently for unmanaged code, an app only ever allocates address space.  It is the job of the OS to map it to RAM.  It does so dynamically, unmapping RAM if necessary and backing up its content to the paging file if necessary.  Standard behavior on any demand-paged virtual memory operating system.

Comment: @HansPassant yes but I thought VirtualMemorySize reports size of commited virtual memory. If OP passes 2GB file to unmanaged C++ library and VirtualMemorySize does not increase after that - that would mean library commited 2GB of virtual memory beforehand?

Comment: Yes.  An unmanaged heap implementation rarely releases address space back to the OS.  Hard to do since it cannot compact a heap and scatters allocations by size to avoid fragmentation problems.  So released memory gets added back to the free list and used again in subsequent allocations.  So the OP cannot test this correctly by loading more than one file at a time, he'll has to restart his program for each file.  The HeapWalk() api might be useful but it is hard to use.

Comment: @HansPassant so I should create a second program that loads the file, run it with `Process.Start` for each file, and measure its `VirtualMemorySize64` ?

Comment: That ought to get you closer.  Do keep in mind that you still don't have a good reason for the OOM.  Read [this web page](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2008/11/17/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-virtual-memory/) for good background info.

Comment: I came roughly to the same conclusion after thinking about that, that's why I asked above "And does VirtualMemorySize64 increases after first call to that c++ dll? And if yes - by how much?" And still it's possible, as I understand, that c++ lib will commit larger chunk of memory than absolutely necessary to hold file you pass to it, then virtual memory size will increase more than really required, even on the first load. But you can test and see yourself I guess.

Comment: @HansPassant : thanks for the link. We haven't yet been able to reproduce the OOM reliably (not tried very hard), but even "just" filling the RAM triggers a lot of swapping, and slows down the app to a crawl, and we also want to prevent this, so we need to prevent this anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @HansPassant comments, I have split my test into 2 programs: one that loads the files, and one that reads the memory measures of the first.
Here they are, cleaned up to remove other measures (like number of items in my json files) and results saving.

The "measures" program:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    foreach (var document in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(JsonFolder)) {
        MeasureMemory(document);
    }
}

private static void MeasureMemory(string document) {
    // run process
    var proc = new Process {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = "loader.exe",
            Arguments = document,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };
    proc.Start();

    // get process output
    var output = string.Empty;
    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
        output += proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine() + "\n";
    }

    proc.WaitForExit();

    // parse process output
    var processMemoryBeforeLoad = long.Parse(Regex.Match(output, "BEFORE ([\\d]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value);
    var processMemoryAfterLoad = long.Parse(Regex.Match(output, "AFTER ([\\d]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value);

    // save the measures in a CSV file
}
```

And the "loader" program:

```
public static int Main(string[] args) {
    var document = args[0];
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(document);

    Console.WriteLine("BEFORE {0}", MeasureMemoryUsage());

    wrapper.LoadFiles(files);

    Console.WriteLine("AFTER {0}", MeasureMemoryUsage());

    wrapper.Unload();

    return 0;
}

private static long MeasureMemoryUsage() {
    // make sure GC has done its job
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();

    return System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().VirtualMemorySize64;
}
```